# Kotlin custom attribute databinding

Tags: kotlin, android-databinding

I am trying to set custom attribute using the [Android DataBinding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)
in my Kotlin project like this:

#### Layout

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgView”
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:imageUrl="@{segment.url}"/>
```

#### Code

```
class Utils {
    companion object {
        @BindingAdapter("bind:imageUrl")
        @JvmStatic
        fun loadImage(view: ImageView, url:String) 
        {Picasso.with(view.context).load(url).error(R.drawable.error).into(view)}
    }
}
```

The runtime error I get is:

> A BindingAdapter in in <package.Utils.Companion> is not static and requires an object to use, retrieved from the DataBindingComponent. If you don't use an inflation method taking a DataBindingComponent, use DataBindingUtil.setDefaultComponent or make all BindingAdapter methods static.

Any pointers to solve it?

This happens only for custom attributes. The rest of the databindings work fine

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Just keep function on the top level, no class or companion object needed, it will work since top-level functions in Kotlin translated to static member functions of Class named as `FileNameKt` unless overridden by `@file:JvmName` annotation

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun loadImage(view: ImageView, url:String) { ... }
```

One more option is to annotate Extension Function as `@BindingAdapter`, it will work since in bytecode signature will exactly match signature expected by DataBindings(generated method will still accept an object of the extended class as the first argument), the function should remain top level as well

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun ImageView.loadImage(url:String) { ... }
```

One more option is to combine `BindingAdapter` with the extension property like following:

```
@set:BindingAdapter("visible")
var View.visible
    get() = visibility == VISIBLE
    set(value) {
        visibility = if (value) VISIBLE else GONE
    }
```

Comment: This answer is still giving me error. Lovis' answer worked for me.

Comment: What about lambdas? How can I assign lambda function in xml layout for custom BindingAdapter in Kotlin?

Comment: @ВладимирШироков yes you can, same as `onClick` works for Views in XML, you'll just need proper SAM class/interface
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BindingAdapter.html

Comment: What about the use of `@JvmStatic`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky all top-level functions is `static` so you don't need to declare it as `@JvmStatic`

Answer (score 43):

Try switching the order of the annotations. It seems to fix the issue:

```
class Utils {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic @BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
        fun loadImage(view: ImageView, url:String) { ... } 
    }
}
```

The problem is that the databindng compiler uses `getCompanion().loadImage` otherwise<sup>*</sup>.
You can verify this in the generated `com.your.package.databinding.*Binding` class

<sup>*</sup> After playing around a bit I noticed that this has nothing to do with the order of the annotations, but seems to be random. It seems to change whenever I hit "rebuild". It might be a bug in `kapt` or in the kotlin compiler

Comment: Same here, changing the order does not help.

Comment: I put a kotlin bug report up https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14417

Comment: Binding look for static method and on providing @JvmStatic inside companion object fixes the problem

Comment: Why do we have to have **companion object**?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky nobody said you _have to_ (see accepted answer), but that's how the question was asked.

Comment: @Lovis Then there is no need for `@JvmStatic`

Answer (score 14):

Adding `@JvmStatic` after `@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")` fixed my problem.

For ex:

```
    @BindingAdapter("android:visibility")
    @JvmStatic
    fun setVisibility(view: View, visible: Boolean) {
        view.visibility = if (visible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
}
```

Comment: This is worked for me thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

Or using extension:

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun ImageView.setImageUrl(url: String?) {
    Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(this)
}
```

Now you can use this function anywhere else

Comment: You need @JvmStatic

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky you need '@JvmStatic' only if you are going to call it from Java code, it's for interop only. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html

Answer (score 3):

This is working for me. Please find it below..

**Add in gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
 kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4"
}
```

**Add in POJO:**

```
companion object {
  @BindingAdapter("image")
    @JvmStatic
         fun loadImage(view: ImageView, imageUrl: String) {

             //am Using Glide
Glide.with(view.context).setDefaultRequestOptions(RequestOptions().circleCrop())
                 .load(imageUrl).into(view)
         }
     }
```

**In Layout:**

Add bind:image="@{movies.imageUrl}

```
<ImageView 
  android:id="@+id/imageView"
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  bind:image="@{movies.imageUrl}/>
```

Comment: Why do you have back-ticks around @BindingAdapter?

Comment: @igorganapolsky sorry.. Typo

Comment: There is absolutely no need for **companion object** with BindingAdapter

Comment: we should give companion object.. bcz we use @JvmStatic. otherwise we get an error.

Comment: `@JvmStatic` is not a requirement

Comment: JvmStatic is must. Without @JvmStatic getting error like "make all BindingAdapter methods static. please check out.

Answer (score 2):

The function(loadImage) need to put in object(Singleton in java) not in class and set `@JvmStatic` before `@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")` like this :

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imgView”
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
imageUrl="@{segment.url}"/>

   @JvmStatic
   @BindingAdapter("bind:imageUrl")
   fun ImageView.loadImage( url:String) {
Picasso.with(this.context).load(url).error(R.drawable.error).into(this)
}
```

Comment: This requires companion object

Comment: '@JvmStatic' handle that, '@JvmStatic' its like companion object !

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
object ImageUtils {

        @JvmStatic @BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
        fun ImageView.loadImage(url: String?){
                GlideHelper.loadImage(url,this)
        }
}
```

in xml like this:

```
imageUrl="@{file.thumbnailLink}"
```