# Kotlin Android - Unable to get @BindingAdapter to work

Tags: android, binding, kotlin

I keep getting the binding error when trying to use the @BindingAdapter. Try for 3 days and follow numerous online articles on this subject, but still getting the below error.

```
@BindingAdapter("focusableColor")
fun setFocusableColor(v:CardView,  color:Int) {
    println("hello")
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
          val binding:ActivityMainBinding  = 
              DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main)
          etc...
    }



In current_task_layout.xml

<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
            <variable name="task" type="com.edenhan.simplytask.Task">
            </variable>
    </data>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
  android:id="@+id/card_view">
  .....
  focusableColor="@{1}"/>
```

Error encountered:

Found data binding errors.

> ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute ‘focusableColor’ with parameter type int on
>   android.support.v7.widget.CardView.
>   file:D:\…….\app\src\main\res\layout\current_task_layout.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried moving the binding out of the companion object?
You should put it in a kotlin file and make it a top level function. For example:

`Bindings.kt`

```
@BindingAdapter("focusableColor")
fun setFocusableColor(v:CardView,  color:Int) {..}
```

And put the binding xml in the app namespace

Also, see [Kotlin custom attribute databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40085724/kotlin-custom-attribute-databinding)

**edit: full example**

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}

@BindingAdapter("focusableColor")
fun setColor(card: CardView, @ColorInt color: Int) {
    // or whatever
    card.setBackgroundColor(color)
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:focusableColor="@{1}"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your suggestion. I just tried your suggestion by moving it outside of the Activity class but within the same kotlin file. But still does not solve the issue.

Comment: Oh, can you add `app` namespace in the xml? `app:focusableColor`

Comment: Hi, i add, but still the same error. Found data binding errors. ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute ‘app:focusableColor’ with ......

Comment: do you wrap your layout in `<layout></layout>`? i just edited my answer. the setup works find for me, tested

Comment: Hi, really thanks for you to dedicate time to reply my questions. 
I have also updated my code to show that I also have the layout element
But i realize that in my onCreate function, I am binding to a different layout.
So let me verify my code with your code sample again. Will let u know if i manage to solve it..

Comment: Even when I shift my cardview xml element to the correct xml . Still has binding issue. The only different now between my code sample and your code sample is the way we set the Content View in our onCreate function. Let me see if i am modify my code to follow yours..and will let u know the result....

Comment: I observe that my gradle does not use the kotlin-kapt plugin, hence suspect that without this kotlin-apt, @bindingadapter annotation could not be used. Can I confirm with you if u use the kotlin-kapt plugin?

Comment: yeah, i use the plugin. your code looks fine to me.

Comment: But i observe that even if u shift the top-level function into a class, and add JvmStatic and BindingAdapter annotations on top of the function, it will also works!

Comment: nice good to know. i learned a quite few things from this :-)

Answer (score 0):

Below defined full code for load image using BindingAdapter with Kotlin

ImageLoader.kt

```
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter
import androidx.databinding.ObservableField

class ImageLoader {

    val imageResource = ObservableField(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @BindingAdapter("android:src")
        fun setImage(imageView: ImageView, imageRes: Int) {
            imageView.setImageResource(imageRes)
        }
    }
}
```

activity_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable name="imageLoader" type="com.sample.testdemo.ImageLoader"/>
    </data>
    <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                   android:src="@{imageLoader.imageResource}"
                   android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

HomeActivity.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import com.sample.testdemo.databinding.ActivityHomeBinding

class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: ActivityHomeBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,  R.layout.activity_home)

        binding.imageLoader = ImageLoader()
    }
}
```

Note: Don't forget to add below line at the top of app level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```